# How can I summarize this function without having to repeat it for each button?

Tags: jquery, arrays, function, for-loop, click

> Maybe something that relates the number of the button and the element
>   to add the class 
>   1 = 1  
>   2 = 2 
>   3 = 3
>    ....

```html
<script>
$('.item-carousel.1').click(function() {
  $('.og-expander:not(.og-expander.1)').removeClass('expander-act');
  $('.og-expander.1').toggleClass('expander-act');
  });
  
  $('.item-carousel.2').click(function() {
  $('.og-expander:not(.og-expander.2)').removeClass('expander-act');
  $('.og-expander.2').toggleClass('expander-act');
  });
    
  $('.item-carousel.3').click(function() {
  $('.og-expander:not(.og-expander.3)').removeClass('expander-act');
  $('.og-expander.3').toggleClass('expander-act');
  });

  $('.item-carousel.4').click(function() {
  $('.og-expander:not(.og-expander.4)').removeClass('expander-act');
  $('.og-expander.4').toggleClass('expander-act');
  });  
  <!-- ... -->
  
  </script>
```

Comment: Refactoring questions are fairly off topic for StackOverflow, and are more suited for CodeReview, if the logic currently works and you can make an example of it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a for loop and loop over an array and create event listeners for each, but the best option would be to give all the similar elements a same class and use [Jquery each function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
<script>
const carousel = [1,2,3,4]
for(let i=0,i<carousel.length; i++ ){

$('.item-carousel.'+carousel[i]+').click(function() {
  $('.og-expander:not(.og-expander.'+carousel[i]+')').removeClass('expander-act');
  $('.og-expander.'+carousel[i]+').toggleClass('expander-act');
  });
} 
  <!-- ... -->

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have back end access to the HTML you could set a data tag

```
<script>
  $('.item-carousel').click(function() {
    var curItem = $(this).data('item')

    $('.og-expander:not(.og-expander.'+curItem+')').removeClass('expander-act');
    $('.og-expander.'+curItem+'').toggleClass('expander-act');
  });
</script>

<div class="item-carousel" data-item="1"></div>
...
```